# Using corner to plot smooth contours

Tags: python, plot, contour

I use corner package to plot contours. But the output figure is not smooth and it has a basic shape and step form:

[image]

Here is the code

```
import corner
fig = corner.corner(samples, labels=["$m$", "$b$", "$\ln\,f$"])
fig.show()
```

Is there any way to use this package and plot smooth graphs? Similar to [this one](http://www.mdpi.com/entropy/entropy-19-00327/article_deploy/html/images/entropy-19-00327-g003.png) or [this one](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRs-drgzKeXvkg7pwZvPZSIvnobzi2uHLRIBk1Qp9ij-4A1FimT)

I appreciate your help and your attention

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `smooth` keyword (see [documentation](http://corner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) for more details) in corner.corner() to smoothen the posterior contours. Implementing it is as simple as setting `smooth=True`.

Answer (score -2):

You could use [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html) to plot these smooth histograms. These smoothed histograms are called kernel density estimations. You can find some examples [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/distplot_options.html), [here for 2D](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/cubehelix_palette.html) and [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html?highlight=kdeplot#seaborn.kdeplot). And [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/pair_grid_with_kde.html) is an example which kinda looks like what you are trying to achieve.